# Viewing file in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to view the contents inside a file called /root/ghamma. Do you know a command that can be used to do so? I tried xdg-open /root/ghamma but that didn't work.

Comment: the `/root` directory can only be read by using `sudo`. Run: `sudo cat /root/ghamma`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
ls -l /root/ghamma
```

to verify it indeed is a file.Make sure you have right permissions.
then

```
gksu gedit /root/ghamma
```

Use gksu instead of sudo for GUI applications.

Comment: It says permission denied. Is there a way to change the file permissions??

Comment: @SweetyPie  can you comment the exact output of command `sudo gedit /root/ghamma` and output of command `sudo ll /root/ghamma` ?

Comment: `ls -l /root` will output nothing but a permission denied error, since you have no .... permissions  :)

Comment: Oh, and please NEVER EVER advice to use `sudo gedit`. Never use sudo on a GUI application. Make it at least `sudo -i gedit`

Comment: The reason i provided the advice of sudo gedit...because this file is under root

Comment: Thanks for editing. `gksu` might not be installed by default, while `sudo -i` always works. You might still want to change `ls -l into` `sudo ls -l` for it to work. It will make an extra upvote :).

Comment: But I guess If we provide root privileges then it should work.